# Measuring mole fraction in lab using Raoult's law

Tags: aqueous-solution

I was reading in my textbook of chemistry on the vapour pressure in liquid compounds, and came across a doubt regarding vapour pressure. If I have two liquids, one is A and another is B, and if I know their vapour pressure in a pure state and their initial mole fraction, would their mole fractions be the same in the vapour phase (after mixing them)? If the answer is yes, how can we prove it? Secondly, if it is practically not possible what other factors should I take into account while solving their value using Raoult's law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mole fractions in the gas phase also depend on the relative volatility of the two liquids, so they will not in general be equal to the mole fractions in the liquid mixture. For instance, if you have components A and B, then their vapor pressures will be

$$ \begin{align} p_A &= \chi_A p^\circ _A \\ p_B &= \chi_B p^\circ _B \end{align}$$

where $\chi_i$ is the mole fraction of component i *in the liquid* and $p^\circ_i$ is the vapor pressure of the component when pure. According to [Dalton's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton's_law) the mole fraction of a given component *in the ideal gas* is proportional to its contribution to the total pressure so that

$$\begin{align}  p&=p_A+p_B \tag{1}\\ &= \chi_A p^\circ _A + \chi_B p^\circ _B \\ &= \chi_A (p^\circ _A -p^\circ _B) + p^\circ _B \end{align}$$

From this last expression you can conclude that the total pressure above the mixture will vary linearly with the mole fraction of either component in the liquid.

You can also show that the mole fraction of either component in the liquid is not equal to that in the gas. For instance for component A you can write by combining Raoult's and Dalton's laws that

$$\chi_{A,g}=\frac{p_A}{p}=\chi_{A,l}\frac{p_A^\circ}{p} \tag{2}$$

where the mole fractions in the liquid and gas are labelled explicitly with subscripts $l$ and $g$. It should be clear that $\chi_{A,g} \neq \chi_{A,l}$ unless $p=p_A^\circ$, but the latter condition is only satisfied for the pure substance A.

Comment: is there any way we can calculate this?@Buck Thorn

Comment: @Yuvraj Please be more specific. Calculate what?

Comment: mole fraction of liquids in the vapor phase?@Buck Thorn

Comment: @Yuvraj Well, you can use the last equation I wrote, $\chi_{A,g}=\chi_{A,l}\frac{p_A^\circ}{p}$. It depends what information you have to start with. If you know the total pressure, the mole fraction in the liquid phase, and the vapor pressure of the pure substance, then you can use this equation.

Comment: The catch with the expression is that it assumes that evaporation to form the vapor phase does not significantly alter the composition of the liquid phase. It's a little more complicated otherwise, and I doubt you need to consider this.

Comment: ok as I have a question where i was given two liquids as I mentioned in the question I know the vapor pressure in their purest form, and their mole fraction liquid phase, so if I want to calculate mole fraction in the vapor phase,what will be total pressure value, using daltons law?@Buck Thorn

Comment: @Yuvraj you can compute the total pressure of the mixture using equation 1 and use the result to compute the mole fraction in the gas phase using equation 2 (I added labels to the relevant equations)